# Hide columns in a GridView when new columns are added

Tags: asp.net, gridview, show-hide

Have landed into a scenario.
I have a gridview with 22 static columns (few are BoundFields, few are TemplateFields).
We have a scenario in our project that we need to order the GridView according to the columns selected. The order of the columns selected is provided from the UI.
For ex: We have Doc1 to Doc23 as the columns.
Now, from the functionality provided in the UI, I am passing some 4 columns say Doc2,Doc4,Doc5,Doc7.
Now I want that only these 4 columns should be present in my grid as a final output.
Have tried some code, but it doesn't seem to work.
Below is my code:

```
    public int GridColumnOrdering(string columnList)
    {
        string[] test = columnList.Split(';');
        var docCatColumn = gridResultSet.Columns[0];
        var docTypeColumn = gridResultSet.Columns[1];
        int columnCount = 0;
        int testCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < test.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (test[i] == "Doc2")
            {
                gridResultSet.Columns.Insert(i , docCatColumn);
                columnCount++;
            }
            if (test[i] == "Doc3")
            {
                gridResultSet.Columns.Insert(i , docTypeColumn);
                columnCount++;
            }
        }
        gridResultSet.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        gridResultSet.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    }
```

columnList is a parameter passed which has values such as Doc2;Doc3.
My idea is that I get the static columns which resemble the column gotten from the UI, change its position to the very next position, and then hide that static column. In this way, we actually have 2 columns by the same name, but I am trying to hide the static one and display the dynamic one.
I know it sounds weird and hectic, but this is what came to my mind.
Now the problem is that if I try to change the visibility of the static column, the visibility of the dynamic one also changes.
Can experts help on this issue or point out to some easy method in this regards??
Regards
Anurag